# Commands invalid after 'import_board_preset' command

Tags: matlab, tcl, fpga, vivado, hdl-coder

Currently I am trying to follow the MathWorks tutorial [1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/hdlcoder/examples/define-and-register-custom-board-and-reference-design-for-zynq-workflow.html) to register a TE0720 with a TE0701-6 carrier board in Matlab. I followed the instructions, designed the block design and exported it as advised. Using the Matlab HDL Workflow Advisor I can follow unitl step 4.1 Create Project. Here, I get the following error message:

```
invalid command name "CONFIG.PCW_INCLUDE_ACP_TRANS_CHECK"
    while executing
"CONFIG.PCW_INCLUDE_ACP_TRANS_CHECK {0}  CONFIG.PCW_IOPLL_CTRL_FBDIV {30}      CONFIG.PCW_IO_IO_PLL_FREQMHZ {1000.000}  CONFIG.PCW_IRQ_F2P_INTR {1}  CONFIG..."
    (procedure "create_root_design" line 49)
    invoked from within
"create_root_design """
    (file "vivado_custom_block_design.tcl" line 986)
    while executing
"source vivado_custom_block_design.tcl"
    (file "vivado_create_prj.tcl" line 15)
```

This is regarding the exported block design in the corresponding *.tlc file.

After deleting the line mentioned in the error, the error persists, but for the following line. This holds true until I deleted all lines following

```
CONFIG.PCW_IMPORT_BOARD_PRESET {preset}
```

It seems to me that once the preset for the board is imported, all following commands are seen as invalid. If I put this line in the end of the list though, I get the error

```
ERROR [Common 17-69] Command failed: Missing name/value pair in -dict argument.
```

If I remove this line, I get the error

```
ERROR [BD 41-1811] The interconnect </axi_interconnect_0> is missing a valid master interface connection
ERROR [Common 17-39] 'validate_bd_design' failed due to earlier errors.
```

Is there a way to fix this or what is the problem here?

**EDIT:**  I am using Vivado 2017.4 from the Vivado HL WebPACK. Could it be that there is a feature not available in this version for rebuilding the project as MATLAB intends to do?

**EDIT 2:** I started the complete tutorial fresh from scratch again and now I only get the error

```
ERROR: [BD 41-1811] The interconnect </axi_interconnect_0> is missing a valid master Interface connection
```

when going throught the HDL Workflow Advisor. As far as I understand the issue, Vivado searches for something to connect the axi_interconnect to. But isn't this the interface port (DUT) as described later in the tutorial (end of step 2 in *Register the custom reference design in HDL Workflow Advisor*, where the compiled simulink model should be connected?

Comment: Are any of these errors in files that you have written? In particular, did you create the `create_root_design` procedure yourself?

Comment: No, I didn't create `create_root_design`. I only created the the block design and the corresponding matlab files as described in the tutorial.